# Showing all of the correlation coefficients in a table

Tags: python, pandas

When I try and show the table of correlation coefficients of all 10 columns of my data set, it shortens the view and has a column of 3 dots to show where data should be. How can I make it so that all of it shows? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Temporary Solution**

```
pd.set_option('display.width', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)
```

You can replace the numeric values with whatever values you'd like.

See here for the full documentation on Pandas set_option. [Pandas set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html)

**Permanent Solution**

See the section `Configure Options & Settings at Interpreter Startup` of the realpython article [Python Pandas: Tricks & Features You May Not Know](https://realpython.com/python-pandas-tricks/) to learn how to set pandas settings permanently.

Comment: Thank you! I added pd.set_option('display.width', 200) and it worked!